# Changing Values with WillSet Property Observer

Tags: ios, swift, frame, cgrect

I am attempting to create a UIView subclass. In the initialization, I set minimum and maximum y-axis origin values I want the subclass to have. This view will be moved up and down programmatically, by user gestures or through an animation. I was hoping I could use the **willSet** property user for this:

```
override var frame: CGRect {
    willSet {
        if newValue.origin.y > maximumOriginY {
            self.frame.origin.y = maximumOriginY
        }
        if newValue.origin.y < minimumOriginY {
            self.frame.origin.y = minimumOriginY
        }
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to do anything. I have tried using **DidSet** property observer, but this resets the origin after it has been set, resulting in a stutter animation. Any ideas on how to get this to work with property observers or another way? Thanks

Comment: both conditions do the same think.

Comment: Post has been edited. There was a typo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it is not possible to change the values within the `willSet` observer. overriding the getter and setter could work:

```
override var frame: CGRect {
    get { return super.frame }
    set {
        var tempFrame = newValue
        tempFrame.origin.y = min(max(tempFrame.origin.y, minimumOriginY), maximumOriginY)
        super.frame = tempFrame
    }
}
```